# tendresse qui parcourt la thèse

Tags: expressions

Source: rapport à propos d'une thèse de doctorat autour du thème "sexe et politique"
Je sais que le mot "tendresse" signifie le sentiment d'affection et d'amour mais il veut dire quoi dans ce contexte:

> Dans cette thèse de doctorat, la sensibilité à la pensée de la post-modernité s’exprime avec un fond d’humour souvent décapant – ce qui n’enlève rien à tout le courant de tendresse qui parcourt la thèse – à propos de l’analyse de l’écriture érotique arabe

Comment: Le sujet de la thèse a un rapport avec la notion de "tendresse" ?

Comment: Comme commenté sur toutes vos questions, merci de rajouter la source de votre citation sur CHAQUE question que vous posez.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment une source. C'est simplement un rapport rédigé en français par mon prof à propos d'une thèse de doctorat d'un étudiant de philosophie, et moi je vaudrai bien en comprendre le contenu.

Comment: Non. Le sujet parle d'une thématique qui est "le sexe et la politique"

Comment: Peu importe d'où vient le texte, que ce soit un livre, une thèse, à l'oral, ou un mail par exemple, le fait de savoir d'où vient le texte nous permet d'adapter nos réponses. Cela nous permet par exemple de remettre en question ou non une potentielle faute de français, et cela nous permet aussi de pouvoir chercher plus d'informations sur le contexte sur Google si nous en ressentons le besoin, ou encore de mieux comprendre l'objectif de l'auteur. C'est donc essentiellement pour vous aider que nous vous demandons cela.

Answer (score 2):

Enlever les mots inutiles :

> ... l'humour souvent décapant ... n’enlève rien ... [au] courant de tendresse ...

*[Souligner le caractère comique, ridicule, absurde ou insolite](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humour)* n’empêche pas l'*[affection,](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendresse)* la *sensibilité et* la *considération bienveillante*.